# Translation of "over 10 years of experience" into German — accusative or dative after "über"?

Tags: grammatical-case

Actually I am trying to translate the following English title into its German equivalent.

> "Lead Software Architect with Management Skills and over 10 years of
>   experience in IT Field"

So the German title:

> "Lead Software Architect mit Management Skills und über 10-jährige
>   Berufserfahrung im IT-Umfeld"

The problem part is:

> "über 10-jährige Berufserfahrung"

Is it correct like this or is this one correct `"über 10-jähriger Berufserfahrung"`? What comes after *über*: the accusative or the dative?

Comment: No. There is no verb, and therefore it is not a sentence. When it's not a sentence, it can't be a correct sentence.

Comment: @user27580 You can hit the "edit" button on the left side below your question to correct typos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Lead-Software-Architekt mit Managementfähigkeiten und mehr als 10 Jahren Berufserfahrung im IT-Umfeld

Personally, I would also change *Lead-Software-Architekt* to *leitender Softwarearchitekt* and *im IT-Umfeld* to *in der IT-Branche*; but this is a matter of taste:

> Leitender Softwarearchitekt mit Managementfähigkeiten und mehr als 10 Jahren Berufserfahrung in der IT-Branche

**Akkusativ vs. dativ:** Here, *mit* refers to both *Managementfähigkeiten* and *10 Jahren Berufserfahrung*. Since *mit* requires the dativ, it is *(mit) 10 Jahre**n*** and not *(mit) 10 Jahre*. The same holds for *(mit) 10-jährige**r*** instead of *(mit) 10-jährige*.

Comment: Yes you are right, I find your title translation way better. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage in this job ad is

> über 10-jähriger Berufserfahrung

When you divide up the sentence you get

> Lead Software Architect mit 10-jähriger Berufserfahrung

"Mit" is a preposition which requires dative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :-) Is it possbile that I also get explaination why it is dativ in this case?

Comment: "mit" demands Dativ ;)

Comment: @user27580 Added explanation for dative.

Answer (score 2):

"Lead Software Architect mit Management skills **mit mehr als** 10-jährige Berufserfahrung im IT-Umfeld"

Instead of `"und"` use `"mit"` and instead of `"über"` use `"mehr als"`.

http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/mehr+als.html

aka. more than or upwards of